# What is "contigs" in Picard's ReorderSAM?

Tags: bioinformatics

I've used BWA to map my NGS reads against the hg38 genome, and I have a BAM file. I'm not doing genome assembly, and my reference genome file has the human chromosomes. Thus, I shouldn't have "contigs". But...

> https://broadinstitute.github.io/picard/command-line-overview.html#ReorderSam

and quote:

> ReorderSam reorders reads in a SAM/BAM file to match the contig ordering in a provided reference file, as determined by exact name matching of contigs

**Q:** What does `contig ordering` mean, for my whole-genome-sequencing experiment? In particular, what does matching the contig against a reference file mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm not familiar with picard and their reorderSam function, but as far as I know/understand from their documentation they mean this:*
The ordering of the contigs while using a reference sequence.
Like this:

> [image] Figure 5: Anatomy of
>   whole-genome assembly. In whole-genome assembly, the BAC fragments
>   (red line segments) and the reads from five individuals (black line
>   segments) are combined to produce a contig and a consensus sequence
>   (green line). The contigs are connected into scaffolds, shown in red,
>   by pairing end sequences, which are also called mates. If there is a
>   gap between consecutive contigs, it has a known size. Next, the
>   scaffolds are mapped to the genome (gray line) using sequence tagged
>   site (STS) information, represented by blue stars. © 2001 American
>   Association for the Advancement of Science Venter, C. et al. The
>   sequence of the human genome. Science 291, 1304–1351 (2001). All
>   rights reserved. ([source](http://www.nature.com/scitable/nated/topicpage/dna-sequencing-technologies-key-to-the-human-828))

**ReorderSAM (Picard)**
So in Picard you have your `INPUT (File)`, the reads in this file are then mapped on the `REFERENCE (File)`. This can also be seen in their code:

```
// write the reads in contig order
109
            for (final SAMSequenceRecord contig : refDict.getSequences() ) {
110
                final SAMRecordIterator it = in.query(contig.getSequenceName(), 0, 0, false);
111
                writeReads(out, it, newOrder, contig.getSequenceName());
112
            }
```

([code source](http://dev.thep.lu.se/basehacks/browser/net.sf.picard/vendor/picard/current/src/java/net/sf/picard/sam/ReorderSam.java?rev=25))

> ReorderSam reorders reads in a SAM/BAM file to match the contig
>   ordering in a provided reference file

**Some more background**
There are two main approches two obtain a genome sequence:

> there are two "main" approches for this: 
>  g. Second-generation
>   sequencing technologies produce millions of short(a few hundred bp)
>   strings of nucleotides (reads), which is ideal for resequencing when
>   reads are mapped to a reference genome (**reference-based assembly**). **De
>   novo genome assembly** based on second-generation sequencing is
>   challenging due to difficulties with GC- or AT-rich and homonucleotide
>   DNA stretches, which are under-represented in the sequencing output ([source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24636622))

The characteristics of these are: 
*de novo*

> - no bias towards a reference genome
> - no template to adapt to
> - the    assembly is normally more fragmented
> - it normally works better for large-scale/median scale differences ([source](https://era7bioinformatics.com/en/page.cfm?id=1500))

*reference mapping*

> - less contigs
> - in most methods the reads that don't map are not used in the final sequence **(this is also the case with reorderSAM: `Reads mapped to contigs absent in the new reference are dropped`**
> - you look what is similar to your reference genome
> - SNPs and very small veriations are more easily positioned and compared among groups ([source](https://era7bioinformatics.com/en/page.cfm?id=1500))

I would highly recommend to watch [this short animation](https://era7bioinformatics.com/en/page.cfm?id=1500) to differentiate between these two and understand what reference genome mapping is.